# Python - Loop last element again

Tags: python, loops, python-3.3

```
a=[1,2,3,4]

for i in a:
    if someConditon:
        print(i)
    else:
        loop over last element again
```

I'm using selenium to interact with a webpage and download pdf documents.  Sometimes an error occurs during the download process and the file doesn't get saved.  The actual saving of the file exists in a for loop and I would like to add in a condition which 'if found to be false' loops over the same element again in an attempt to successfully download the item.

My question is: How do I tell python to loop over the same element again

Comment: You should instead ask: How do I retry a failed action? Because that is what you are trying to achieve. Don't immediately jump for a possible solution; see [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: Are there any side-effects you are causing by the iteration? Otherwise if you are still in the loop body when your condition fails, you still have that last element at hand to do whatever you like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to tell a for loop to not advance the iterator, so instead you will either need to use a while loop and manually increase `i`, or perform any additional looping within the body of your for loop.  Here is how I would write this:

```
for i in a:
    while not someCondition:
        # do something
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop and control when your index gets incremented. In this case `i` will only get incremented if the `someCondtion` is True. otherwise it will loop over the same element again and again. You can add logic to avoid infinite repetitions, such as after X number of retries exit the loop or increment to the next index.

```
a=[1,2,3,4]

while i < len(a):
    if someCondition:
        print a[i]
        i += 1
```